# Can I use Basmati Rice for fried rice?

Tags: substitutions, rice, asian-cuisine

I have some left over boiled Basmati Rice in the fridge and I was wondering if anyone has ever used it to make [Chinese Fried Rice](http://bakerette.com/better-than-take-out-chicken-fried-rice/) given that the recipes generally call for Jasmin rice? Does it have huge flavor differences or should it be ok given that other Asian flavors like Soy sauce and sesame oil add flavor to the dish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely you can! It's a popular choice with Chinese and Indian flavor profiles. You can just treat it exactly like you would any other leftover rice. It's a lovely ingredient to work with. The nutty Basmati flavor works beautifully however you choose to season fried rice.

[image: rice]

Comment: Thanks was just a bit confused coz I thought that Jasmine rice is more suited to Asian cooking and Basmati to Indian and whether its because of their textures and flavors

Comment: @Divi Check out what this [article about Chinese fried rice](http://chinesefood.about.com/od/rice/a/How-To-Make-Rice-For-Fried-Rice.htm) has to say. "While Jasmine is a long grain rice, it contains less amylose than regular long grain white rice and cooks up slightly sticky. Basmati rice, which contains a higher percentage of amylose, is a better choice."

Comment: @Divi Indian food *is* Asian food.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Sorry, wrong choice of words. I mean Indian cuisine vs other parts of Asian cuisine

Comment: Why does "other parts" of Asia all get lumped together? They're all quite different =.=

Comment: I think this is one of those UK/US English things: in US English, "Asian" usually means "East Asian" (Chinese, Japanese, Vietnamese, etc), in UK English, "Asian" usually means "South Asian" (India, Pakistan, Bangladesh etc).

Comment: @user568458: That's what I meant, thanks for helping with the clarification

Comment: @Jolenealaska: It turned out very nice, no problems with the Basmati rice. Can't say it was exactly like a take away but as far as the rice goes, I didn't find any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can with bashmati rice but jasmine rice is preferred because it relatively smaller and gives out an aroma which suits fried rice. Bashmati rice aroma varies with the quality that you buy from the market. At the same time the greater length of the bashmati makes it stick less compared to that of jasmine rice.

Comment: I find the aroma of Basmati superior to Jasmine for fried rice, I also like the larger grains. The protein difference makes Basmati less sticky. All in all, I disagree with the assertion that Jasmine is generally preferred for fried rice, but it's certainly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: Yes you are correct to say it's about personal preference. However, fried rice is a popular or trademark dish of South-East Asia esp. Thailand and commonly grown staple there is jasmine rice and therefore it has been used for making fried rice for ages.

Answer (score 1):

We use Basmati rice all the time for making fried rice as we have basmati leftovers everyday . It is cooked as plain rice everyday at home. Basmati will take on the flavours of whatever you are adding . It is long grained and non-sticky , so it could be an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! In fact, I try to use anything other than plain white rice when I make fried rice! Any leftover rice is better than fresh, since it fries better after drying out in your refrigerator. (I like to use equal parts white and brown rice, or cook the rice in beer instead of water, to get more depth of flavor in the resulting fried rice.) You can also chop up and add any leftover meat or veggies to the dish - if they're already cooked, add them at the very end so they just warm up.

My secret to really great fried rice is to spread it out in the pan as much as possible and let it cook until the grains on the bottom get a little browned. Then I'll usually toss the rice and let it happen a second time. If you're using a non-stick pan, getting it too hot can be dangerous, so this can take a while on medium heat - if you're using cast-iron, stainless, or carbon steel, you can just turn the heat all the way up and let it get "too hot to stick."